# Сосульки и леденцы

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а почему сосульки называются сосульками? А вот, кстати, то, что действительно бы правильно было так назвать, именуется леденцами. Где логика?)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Жанна Варбот, доктор филологических наук :"Слово «сосулька» действительно связано с глаголом «сосать» . В славянских языках словом «сосать» называли кормление ребенка грудью. А когда мать выходила с ребенком в поле, она клала его в тенек и давала соску в виде разжеванного хлеба, завернутого в тряпочку. В некоторых говорах ее называли «рожок» , в других – «сосуля» . В дальнейшем это слово перенеслось на другие похожие предметы. Например, на леденец или пряник продолговатой формы. Даль писал о пряничных или медовых сосульках. В ярославских говорах так называют вытянутый редис, некоторые формы цветов. Очевидно, по той же аналогии назвали висячую наледь на крышах. Кстати, у того же Даля находим прозвище «сосульник» – это человек, постоянно сосущий ледяные сосульки"

Итак, сосулька названа по аналогии с соской.

А вот леденец по Фасмеру (http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6788.htm )  от лёд, ледяно́й (Преобр. I, 444), но не лёд в значении "холодный", а как  лёд прозрачный (Ср. чеш. ledovati "засахаривать").

Это плавленый сахар, прозрачный, как лёд.

Поэтому и поменялись значениями:  сосулька из льда, а леденец из сахара.

Answer (score 0):

Сосулька от сосать, потому что их все нормальные дети их сосали, лизали и тд. То есть сосулька это вполне себе источник чистой воды, лучше снега, ну и так как это ледышка сосать её весьма приятно, эффект как у мороженого. А леденец уже от сосульки, потому что их сосут как сосульки, а не наоборот. Это сейчас снег грязный, особенно в городах и сосулек не достать, а леденцы в магазинах круглый год.